# Unable to find interface controller class 'InterfaceController' to instantiate

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-watch

I'm getting this error every-time I run the project and try to navigate to another screen.

```
Unable to find interface controller class 'HelpInterfaceController' to instantiate
```

I'm using the correctly that I know: 
`- (IBAction)HelpButton {
    [self presentControllerWithName:@"help" context:nil]; }`

Also the name `help` is as it is in the identifier.
So what or where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found the error! It was because of my .m file, it's target membership was `MemGame` instead of `MenGame WatchKit Extension`. So I uncheck the first option and selected the third option and now it's running perfectly.
[image: Solution]

Comment: In case anyone is looking for the "Target Membership" area, just click on the file (e.g. InterfaceController.m) and then the "File Inspector" (paper icon ) in the right side-pane. The Target Membership area is in the middle.