# WatchKit: unable to find interface controller class

Tags: ios, storyboard, watchkit

I tried adding an interface controller to a storyboard, setting its Custom Class to a WKInterfaceController subclass, launched the app in the simulator and navigated to the specified interface controller.

When I do so, I get the following error:

> WatchKit error - unable to find interface controller class 'TestController' to instantiate

If I try to interact with the controller (e.g. try launching its button's action), I get the following error:

> - *********** ERROR -[SPRemoteInterface _interfaceControllerClientIDForControllerID:] clientIdentifier for interfaceControllerID:(null) not found
> - *********** ERROR -[SPRemoteInterface _interfaceControllerClientIDForControllerID:] clientIdentifier for interfaceControllerID:7120004 not found

I tried [setting the module name as recommended on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28364797/35690), but that still gives me the following errors:

> - WatchKit error - unable to find interface controller class '_TtC29myWatchApp_WatchKit_App19TestController' to instantiate
> - *********** ERROR -[SPRemoteInterface _interfaceControllerClientIDForControllerID:] clientIdentifier for interfaceControllerID:(null) not found
> - *********** ERROR -[SPRemoteInterface _interfaceControllerClientIDForControllerID:] clientIdentifier for interfaceControllerID:6E20004 not found

Answer (score 35):

I got this error after renaming the WatchKit target, but finally realized: if you rename your WatchKit targets, you'll have to go through the interfaces in Interface Builder and make sure the module names for each of them is renamed as well.

You can do this by selecting an interface controller, clicking the Identity Inspector (or command-option-3), delete the module name, then tab away. It will automatically be filled in with the new target name. That did it for me!

Comment: Alternatively, tick the option that says "Inherit from Target". This ensures that should you change the name again you won't have to do the same exercise (it'll automatically work).

Answer (score 16):

This error came up for me because I was not properly handling the `didDeactivate` message. My deactivated controller was still receiving messages via `MMWormhole`. Once I severed that connection, the error went away. It turns out that in the simulator all the deactivated interface controllers hang around in memory, so you have to carefully make sure they don't get any more messages of any kind. I don't know if this happens on the Watch itself, but of course we should assume so.

Comment: If you are using MMWormhole make sure you stop listening for messages in didDeactivate as follows: self.wormhole.stopListeningForMessageWithIdentifier("identifier"). This got rid of the error for me.

Comment: I am using MMWormhole and this is a great tip, error or not. I was disabling my delegate callback but not the listening block itself.

Answer (score 11):

I spent way too much time with this issue, but finally figured what it was.
The Apple Watch has basically two navigation patterns:

Hierarchical:

```
[self pushControllerWithName:@"controllerName" context:nil];
```

Page-based:

```
[[self class] reloadRootControllersWithNames:@[@"controller1",@"controller2"] contexts:nil];
```

According to apple:

> You cannot combine hierarchical and page-based interface styles. At design time, you must choose the style that best suits your app’s content and design for that style.

So, the issue is that I was mixing both and that leads to undefined behavior like:

> *********** ERROR -[SPRemoteInterface _interfaceControllerClientIDForControllerID:] clientIdentifier for interfaceControllerID:(null) not found

Hope this helps other developers

**EDIT:**

Just a suggestion that worked for me as a workaround, when using Page-based navigation you can still present modal controllers (just saying):

```
[self presentControllerWithName:@"controllerName" context:nil];
```

Comment: Thx - I ended up redesigning app so that my logged in view is same page as logged out view and simply hide / show elements according to state. Works ok.

Comment: Thx, I dropped my table from the design but still had 'push' controllers, changed to 'present' and fixed error.

Answer (score 7):

This bug seems to be closely related to this one: [Unable to see custom classes in Interface Builder drop down](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28386081/35690).

When I originally tried solving this, I had to manually type in the module name since the drop down was empty for both the custom classes and the module names.

Examining the storyboard's source code reveals one workaround.

Interface controllers that work look like this:

```
<controller id="AgC-eL-Hgc" customClass="InterfaceController" 
  customModule="myWatchApp_WatchKit_App" customModuleProvider="target">
```

Interface controllers that don't work lack the `customModule` and/or the `customModuleProvider` attribute(s).

Therefore, a workaround is to manually add those missing attributes to the storyboard file by right-clicking it and choosing **Open As > Source Code**.

A longer-term solution may be to fix the storyboard so that custom classes appear in the drop downs (see [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28386081/35690) for some potential fixes).

**Update:**

Other interface controllers that also work use `customModule="myWatchApp_WatchKit_Extension"` (notice the `_Extension` vs. `_App` difference) and don't need the `customModuleProvider` attribute.

Answer (score 4):

For me, this appears to be a false negative. I tried all suggested solutions, but then proved it's an Apple error by creating a brand new Apple Kit project, making one change to the Glance (adding an image) and getting the error.  I've logged the following error with Apple in their Bug Reporter.

Title

> Receive clientIdentifier for interfaceControllerID not found when
>   navigating to Glance

Description

> I receive the following error which appears to be a false negative
>   when navigating to a Glance in a watchOS 2.0 project.  I reproduced
>   this by creating a brand new Apple Kit project, making one change to
>   the Glance (adding an image) and getting the error.

Steps to reproduce

> 1. Clear all data in both watch and iOS simulators.
> 2. In XCode, create a new WatchKit application including complication and glance.
> 3. Run and see no issues.
> 4. Add a png to your image assets.
> 5. Add a UIImageView to the Glance in Interface Builder.
> 6. Run the extension in the watch simulator.
> 7. Enable the Glance in the iOS Watch companion app.
> 8. Navigate to the Glance in the watch simulator.
> 9. Note the follow error in your log.
>
> 2015-07-16 08:35:10.663 restaurant-reports WatchKit App
>   Extension[78301:2211560] *********** ERROR -[SPRemoteInterface
>   _interfaceControllerClientIDForControllerID:] clientIdentifier for interfaceControllerID:3118001E not found

Expected result

> No false negatives should appear in log

Actual result

> False negative appears in log

Watch OS version (build)

> 2.0 (13S5293f)

They gave me bug id 21853566.

Comment: I am also seeing this issue with Glances. I prepared a sample project to test the issue: https://github.com/benmorrow/TestGlances/

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix this by removing `didSet` observers from my `IBOutlet`s. tymac's troubleshooting code was helpful. It seems that the interface elements were not available yet, as `didSet` was getting called before `awake(withContext:)`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to use the storyboardID to your class. That's what i get from your error.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when I renamed the WatchKit target. When I renamed it back the error went away.

Answer (score 2):

The better way to do a push/pop controller is running that piece of code into the main thread so:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     [self pushControllerWithName:@"controllerIdentifier" context:data];
});

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     [self popToRootController];
});

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     [self popController];
});
```

Apple documentation says about the three methods:

> Always call this method from your WatchKit extension’s main thread.

Answer (score 1):

You need to verify the view controller is in your compile source here: Select Project > Select Watchkit Extension Target > Build Phases > Compile Sources

Answer (score 0):

It's not anything you're doing wrong. This is already a known issue. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28610801/1342462). Please dupe the following [radar](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5296776269529088) on Apple's [Bug Reporting System](http://bugreport.apple.com/) to help raise the priority to get this fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issues after the recent 8.2 release. I had to go to each one of my InterfaceControllers and adjust its custom class module to whatever was shown as an option or "none".

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I mistakenly set root interface controller's identifier. When I remove the identifier, this warning disappeared.

[image]

Comment: That was the opposite for me. Setting the root interface controller's identifier did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The controller’s Module name should be the same name as your Project’s root name (top left blue Xcode document icon name).

[image]

Your dynamic interface’s module name should be that same name and your destination controller’s module name (i.e. the one you're pushing to) should also be the same name.

Btw, in case you’re new or not sure I thought I’d throw this in because you might be thinking your class is wrong or something. Your Dynamic Interface Controller doesn’t have to point to the default Xcode NotificationController.swift class. Of course you can create a custom class i.e. FriendRequestNotificationController

To troubleshoot you can add this code into awakeWithContext method to see what controllers have what IDs.

```
override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)
    if let vcID = self.valueForKey("_viewControllerID") as? NSString {
        print("Controller: \(vcID)")
    }

    // Configure interface objects here.
}
```

Comment: Very helpful bit of debugging code - used it to track down a fix in my case (solution posted).

Answer (score 0):

- If you are using page-based navigation (from where you are handling
  push or presenting a new view controller) then please *present*
  the new controller instead of *pushing* it.
- Since first screen which if page based (like page view controller)
  screens, then it by default uses pushing of next page or previous
  page on swiping left and right and it becomes root window view of
  your WatchKit app. In this case if you *push* another controller on
  click from inside controls then it will not recognise the push *but
  it will recognise present* new controller. Hence please do follow
  the rules if possible.