# Compiling problems I am new to programming could someone check out my project file and see what's wrong with it

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, apple-watch

It would be really great if anyone could get it running again since it was running before on the Apple watch as well as the simulator
Xcode project

Comment: i am able to successfully run your project. there is no issue.

Comment: Does the watch app work for you for me it freezes in the loading screen I also get the error unable to attach I was working on an update to include some bug fixes however it stopped working for me for no apparent reason?

Comment: yes. it is working in me .

Comment: it's working bro...@ferdinand

Comment: That is great news @ Abdul Karim @ Badal Shah but do you have any idea why it's  not working for me? I spent the last three hours trying to work it out but no  success yet :( also tried clean as well restarting my computer

Comment: I can compile, but I think you have some issues here: `2016-02-27 15:46:20.017 Watch calculator 1 Extension[70005:3180758] WatchKit error - unable to find interface controller class '_TtC28Watch_calculator_1_Extension19InterfaceController' to instantiate
2016-02-27 15:46:20.019 Watch calculator 1 Extension[70005:3180758] WatchKit error - unable to find interface controller class 'InterfaceController' to instantiate` 
Check this though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29069200/watchkit-unable-to-find-interface-controller-class

Comment: @Fennec I checked the post out, however, I tried the suggested solutions but they didn't work for me.  The first answer looked hopeful, however, I tried this answer but the module in the identity inspector did not autofill.  If you were to try this would it work for you?

Comment: @FerdinandLösch I think you have an issue in the App ID. Please check that.

Comment: @Fennec Are you talking about the APP identifier?  Sorry, I am new to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologies for my 1st comment. I made mistake to understand your question. and run your project in iphone simulator. but , now  I have successfully solved your issue .

You have set **InterfaceController** as class of both the controller in storyboard .

I have attach image with your issue.

**Issue:-**

[image]

Here i have attached your app result .

**Apple Watch Simulator Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for  the help @ Badal ShahI have tried your suggestion  I can now successfully built the project however it still freezes in the Watch simulator

Comment: This is a nice answer, but "guys, please fix my project for me" type of questions really shouldn't be answered, they should be closed. It'll only encourage people to treat Stack Overflow as a free project fixing service.