# WatchKit interfaceController not found

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, watchkit, wkinterfacecontroller

When running my App I get an error that an interface controller was not found, which crashes the app in runtime.

```
AppNameWatchExtension[809:615971] [default] -[SPRemoteInterface _interfaceControllerWithID:]:2087: ComF: interfaceController for interfaceControllerID:3290002 not found (clientIdentifier=(null))
```

Funny enough the project works perfectly fine in the simulator, but the error is still shown. On a physical watch it crashes with a memory issue

```
Thread 1: EXC_RESOURCE RESOURCE_TYPE_MEMORY (LIMIT=80 MB, unused=0x0)
```

I also checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29069200/watchkit-unable-to-find-interface-controller-class/29852659), which wasn't helpful for me. I have a page based Application and no other controller gets pushed/popped/loaded. I do have a `SpriteKit Scene` setup inside the `InterfaceController`, which might cause the problem. Hopefully someone of you can help me out.

That is my scene:

```
class MyScene : SKScene {    
   override func sceneDidLoad() {
      let image = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "image")
      self.addChild(image)

   }
}
```

This is my `InterfaceController` where I load my created scene in the storyboard.

```
@IBOutlet var myScene: WKInterfaceSKScene!

override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
    super.awake(withContext: context)

    if let scene = MyScene(fileNamed: "MyScene") {
        myScene.presentScene(scene) 
    }
}
```

And the relevant part of the storyboard. Its just a Scene inside the controller.

[image]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of your storyboard and some code?